# Should we rename the [star-wars] tag to [fairy-tale-rubbish]?

Tags: discussion, retagging

In honour of TFA release, I propose we rename the [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) tag to [fairy-tale-rubbish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tale-rubbish)?

Reference: [What has been Alec Guinness's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111996/alec-guinness-attitude-toward-star-wars)

We can keep [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) as a synonym, to avoid confusing posters.

Comment: lol, this is funny.

Comment: @RedCaio - my ESL ears are showing. That, or i'm just too lazy to spellcheck.

Comment: ESL? What's your first language?

Comment: @RedCaio - that's a puzzle easily solvable by my posts on the main site, including reasonably recent ones! So I'm leaving it as excercise for the reader :)

Comment: @DVK Exercise.:)

Comment: @user14111 - ironyc.

Comment: just in case you didn't have the Sun Wukong hat yet, here's a +1.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - I did. Thanks for the intent though. I don't need to work TOO hard to get tons of downvotes on Meta :)

Comment: A *meta* question flagged as "primarily opinion-based"? Someone doesn't know what meta is all about ...

Answer (score 9):

I have given this serious consideration and my answer is

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Needs a gif from the TFA.

Comment: @CreationEdge - I haven't seen it yet. Please don't edit one in.

Comment: I don't think they exist yet, but I expect you to come back in and edit one yourself after they're released no disc ;)

Comment: @CreationEdge Does anyone even exclaim "NO!!!" in TFA?

Comment: @RedCaio I'm pretty sure Chewie does

Comment: @Richard - http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/JJ-Abrams-Chewbacca-888x456.png   . I promise it is in NO WAY spoilery

Comment: @RedCaio - see #32 in this epic answer.: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112253/976

Comment: @DVK Self-promotion alert ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - it's not my fault I answered stuff :)

Comment: @DVK - Between your hat-whoring and TFA-acceptance-whoring, you're going to struggle to find time stuff yourself with mince pies and eggnog.

Comment: @Richard - good thing I don't consume either even outside providing quality content on SFF, then.

Comment: Also, you're just sore I beat you on hats and rep this week :) pthththth </jar-jar>

Comment: @DVK - I'm looking forward to correcting some of your TFA answers since  I've noted that you don't have the junior novelisation of the film.

Comment: @Richard - In all honesty, with all the time spent answering, I didn't even have time to read the *real* novelization end to end in proper order. I think I read 100% of it, but it was bits and pieces, like Rey's LSD trip.

Comment: I can't find any gif, but if I'm not mistaken, at the very beggining when Finn's buddy gets killed (the Storm Trooper) he yells 'no'. If not, use Chewbacca's (You know what I mean if you saw the movie)